# Custom Shape overlay in Google Maps

Tags: google-maps

Objective: I'm trying to trace the NYC Boroughs in an overlay to google maps.

Issue: I can't find a proper shape. If i go to google maps and search for Bronx, I will get a nice outline of the Bronx. My problem is none of the shapes in the google documentation seem to fit with what i'm trying to do. The best match looks like a polygon, but that doesn't work well with all of the borders because of all the jaggedness. I'm trying to use overlays because I need them to be clickable

https://maps.google.com/maps?q=manhattan&ie=UTF-8&hq=&hnear=0x89c2588f046ee661:0xa0b3281fcecc08c,Manhattan,+New+York,+NY&gl=us&ei=thEQUISLBO610AG4qYDYCA&ved=0CKkBELYD

vs

http://jsfiddle.net/xHKB7/5/

I don't need to individually trace each island, as what I'm doing is not that precise - but if you look at queens i don't see how i can reasonably use a polygon to capture this shape

https://maps.google.com/maps?q=manhattan&ie=UTF-8&hq=&hnear=0x89c2588f046ee661:0xa0b3281fcecc08c,Manhattan,+New+York,+NY&gl=us&ei=thEQUISLBO610AG4qYDYCA&ved=0CKkBELYD

I've tried starting at the center, and then tracing the border because i've found this to give me the best detail from all sides, but it obviously leaves this ugly line.

http://jsfiddle.net/xHKB7/6/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FusionTables contains some data that might be useful to you:

[Bronx - from New York State counties](https://www.google.com/fusiontables/DataSource?snapid=S595151csEn)

[Richmond Cty (Staten Island) - from New York State counties](https://www.google.com/fusiontables/DataSource?snapid=S595158Z_90)

[(from this page)](http://support.google.com/fusiontables/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1182141)

Not sure if this is any better than the one you drew.